# declaring scalar variables in dynamic sql where parameters are dynamic

Tags: sql-server

I am continuing to have trouble with some dynamic SQL syntax in a long stored procedure I'm working on.

```
SET @Columns='OP__DOCID,OP__PARENTID,OP__FOLDERID,'+@ColumnSql
SET @Values='@NEWDOCID,@CLIENTKEY,@CLIENTKEY,'+@ValueSql

SET @sqlCommand= 'INSERT INTO '+@Table+' ('+@Columns+')
                  VALUES ('+@Values+')'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

The `@ColumnSql` and `@ValuesSql` comes from a varchar(MAX) field in a table that I've already selected and each `@table` can have a different set of columns and values. As I am testing `@ValuesSql` it is `'@ClientKey,@AdmissionKey,@PgmAdmissionKey'`. When I try to run the above code I get "Must  declare the scalar variable "@ClientKey"." message. Now I imagine I could use `sp_executesql` but since the parameters differ, I can't hard code them in to to the `@params` section. Is there some basic syntax errors I'm making or a work around for this?

Comment: What is the value for `@NEWDOCID`?

Comment: @T.Rahgooy It is an int that is an OUTPUT from and EXEC above: `EXEC TP_CreateNewTierFormID -3
                           , @FormName
                           , @ClientKey
                           , 'TTierDocument'
                           , 'TP__AutoCreateDocs'
                           , @NEWDOCID OUTPUT`

Comment: @T.Rahgooy I've set `@values=CAST(@NEWDOCID AS VARCHAR(7))+'@ClientKey....`, but since `@ValueSql` can be any number of parameters, I can't cast each individually. Does that make sense?

Comment: The values of `@NEWDOCID,@CLIENTKEY,@CLIENTKEY` comes from where? you should declare them before and set the value for them

Comment: I changed it to `SET @Values=CAST(@NEWDOCID AS VARCHAR(7))+','+CAST(@ClientKey AS VARCHAR(7))+','+CAST(@ClientKey AS VARCHAR(7))+','+@ValueSql` and get `Must declare the scalar variable "@AdmissionKey".` which is the first parameter listed in the `@ValueSql` parameter